# `Permission denied (publickey)` when key is added to SSH-Agent via Bash script

Tags: ssh, bash-scripting, ssh-agent

On both my mobile device and Raspberry Pi (coincidentally AArch and ARM CPUs respectively), `ssh-agent` is not loaded by default.

I first have to start the `ssh-agent`:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

I then proceed to add the key to the agent:

`ssh-add /home/jimjamz/.ssh/myKey`

I'm prompted for a password and enter it.  The key is then added to the agent:

```
Enter passphrase for /home/jimjamz/.ssh/myKey: 
Identity added: /home/jimjamz/.ssh/myKey (/home/jimjamz/.ssh/myKey)
```

I can then connect to my remote server without having to specify my key once again.

For the sake of convenience, I want to add the above to a script that starts the agent and adds the key:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add /home/jimjamz/.ssh/myKey
```

When I run the script, I can see the agent process has started and I'm prompted for my private key's password.  I enter this correctly and the key is added to the agent.

However, when I try to ssh to my remote server, I see the following:

`Permission denied (publickey).`

The problem seems to be with calling `ssh-add` within my bash script.  If I manually call `ssh-add` outside of the script then attempt to ssh to my remote server, I can connect.

Why is it not recognising that the key is already added if `ssh-add` is called within a bash script?

If I run the bash script on one of my other machines (where ssh-agent is already loaded by default), the key that is added within the script can be used successfully to ssh to a remote server.  It just appears not to work on devices where ssh-agent is not automatically running by default.

Comment: `eval`ing the output of `ssh-agent` sets the environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to the location of the agent's communication socket. Shell scripts run as subprocesses, so setting it in the subprocess's environment has no effect on your shell's environment (and hence the `ssh` command you run from it). Try running the script with the `source` command (or `.`), which runs it in the current shell rather than a subprocess.

Comment: Yes, of course, I forgot about `source`.  I use `source` to also configure environment variables for terminal windows where the variables are only required.  This is the answer.  @GordonDavisson If you would like to convert your comment into an answer, I can mark it as answered.